# libvips and padding when doing image pyramids

Tags: image-processing, gdal, vips

I am trying to do a pyramid of tiles with a non-square image `(width: 32768px and height: 18433px)`

I am using `libvips` as follows:

```
vips dzsave my_image.tif out_folder --layout google --suffix .png
```

For the same purpose I have also used `gdal2tiles`:

```
python gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-7 -w none my_image.tif
```

Because my image is not square, some padding is necessary when the `256x256` tiles are created. Padding however is different between `vips` and `gdal2tiles`. The former adds padding at the bottom of the tile where as the latter at the top (and is trasparent). See image below. What is shown in the the `256x256` tile at the root of the pyramid (ie `zoom level=0`). I have manually added the yellow background and the black outline.

With `vips`, is it possible to have similar padding to `gdal2tiles` so that the bottom-left corner of the tile coincide with that from the image? I am plotting points on my image, hence it helps to have the origin at the bottom-left.

How can I also have transparent background with `vips`? (that might better be in a separate post though...)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `dzsave` as the output of any vips operation by using `.dz` as the file extension and putting the arguments in square brackets after the filename. For example, this command:

```
vips dzsave my_image.tif out_folder --layout google --suffix .png
```

Can also be written as:

```
vips copy my_image.tif out_folder.dz[layout=google,suffix=.png]
```

So you can solve your problem by expanding your input image to a square before running dzsave.

For example:

```
$ vips gravity Chicago.jpg dir.dz[layout=google,suffix=.png,skip_blanks=0] south-west 32768 32768 --extend white
```

32768 is the nearest power of two above that image width. The `skip_blanks` option makes dzsave not output tiles equal to the blank background tile.

That command makes this `dir/0/0/0.png`:

[image]

(I added the black lines to show the edges)

To get a transparent background, you need to add an alpha. This would require another command, and is beyond what the vips CLI is really designed for.

I would switch to something like Python. With [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/), for example, you can write:

```
import sys
import pyvips

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')

im = im.addalpha()

# expand to the nearest power of two larger square ... by default, gravity will
# extend with 0 (transparent) pixels
size = 1 << int.bit_length(max(im.width, im.height))
im = im.gravity('south-west', size, size)

im.dzsave(sys.argv[2], 
          layout='google', suffix='.png', background=0, skip_blanks=0)
```

Run like this:

```
$ ./mkpyr.py ~/pics/Chicago.jpg x
```

To make this `x/0/0/0.png`:

[image]

(added the green background to show the transparency)

Comment: Thanks John! The CLI is fine, I need to do that from Matlab but also for Python, hence I am thinking to use the command line especially from Matlab. I havent been able to experiment with the Python script, i tried to install vips but I get  a weird error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'` but that might be because of my Python. I installed `Python 3.7.2` a week ago and something doesnt look right. May I also ask why the tile has olive green background? where is this set and how it is related to alpha.

Comment: Sounds like the cffi module failed to install correctly, perhaps you don't have libffi installed? I added the olive green background to show the transparent area, I'll add a note.